# Valid AJAX request with Spring MVC

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I'm trying to send an `AJAX` jQuery request to my `Spring MVC` Servlet and got some problems. I read some articles already but they didn't help me :(
So I have this `ajax` request:

```
            $.ajax({
                url         : "add_news",
                type        : "POST",
                dataType    : 'json',
                contentType : 'application/json',
                mimeType    : 'application/json',
                data        : JSON.stringify({"category": categoryName, "name": newsName, "data": newsData}),
                success     : function(data) {
                    $("#list_news").append(
                            data.id + " : " +
                            data.name + " - " +
                            data.created + " ; " +
                            data.data + "<br>");
                }
            });
```

Controller is:

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/add_news", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody News addNews(@RequestParam String category, @RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String data) {
    System.out.println("category " + category);
    System.out.println("name " + name);
    System.out.println("data " + data);

    NewsCategoryDict c = new NewsCategoryDict();
    c.setId(66);
    c.setName("misc");

    News response = new News();
    response.setCategory(c);
    response.setId(60);
    response.setName(name);
    response.setData(data);
    response.setCreated(new java.util.Date());

    return response;
}
```

I don't even get System out - so my first problem is with url. "add_news" is not a `jsp` - just a logic to get a record from server.
Second problem (if I undestand it right) in entry params. I have to use `@RequestBody` to get data from the client as Java POJO and send this POJO back with some additional info. But I don't understand how to write `JSON` body in `AJAX.data` right to make it valid.
Please help me.

EDIT
Ok. I find a moment. If I use GET in $.ajax AND set RequestMethod.GET in controller handler method - method is invoked (with POST - no actions). So why POST is not working ??

Answer (score 0):

Remove `JSON.stringify()` from post data:

```
$.ajax({
    url         : "add_news",
    type        : "POST",
    dataType    : 'json',
    contentType : 'application/json',
    mimeType    : 'application/json',
    data        : {"category": categoryName, "name": newsName, "data": newsData},
    success     : function(data) {
        $("#list_news").append(
                data.id + " : " +
                data.name + " - " +
                data.created + " ; " +
                data.data + "<br>");
    }
});
```

Comment: So this means @RequestParam in my method will be in order like AJAX.data? And what about URL - i don't have any println in Controller?

Comment: Why GET method works and POST method doesn't invoke Controller?

Comment: When you used `GET`, did you use `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: No. I remove it and all works fine. But with Post Controller just not react